# block vector matrix SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

assuming I have two matrices and there SVD's

$$
A = U_A \Sigma_A V_A^T \\
S = U_S \Sigma_S V_S^T
$$

does that necessarily mean that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
A \\
S 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 
U_A & 0 \\
0 &  U_S 
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 
\Sigma_A & 0 \\
0 &  \Sigma_S 
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 
V_A^T \\ V_S^T
\end{bmatrix}
$$

is one of the possible SVD of $\begin{bmatrix} 
A \\
S 
\end{bmatrix}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because your matrix of right singular vectors is $[V_A, V_S]$ is not unitary. If $A$ and $S$ have $N$ columns, then $[V_A, V_S]$ is going to be $N \times 2N$ which cannot be a unitary matrix. To find a suitable $V$, you'd need the eigenvectors of $A^T A + S^T S$ or so.

That said, $\begin{bmatrix}U_A & 0 \\ 0 & U_S\end{bmatrix}$ does qualify for a matrix of left singular vectors, as it is unitary and spans the right space.

The singular values are influenced by both $U$ and $V$ so they will change as well.

Comment: can i find an svd for  the combine matrix with the svd's of A and S?

Comment: Not directly I think. You need to connect the two matrices, e.g. via the SVD of $A^T A+ S^T S$.